# How long should it take to load from LiveUSB

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 from a USB and it's been booting from the USB for at least an hour now.  I always installed from a DVD before and I remember it takes a really long time (at least it did last time), but this seems even longer than I remember.
How long before I decide something's wrong and I need to try something else?  What else should I try?

I'm on a Lenovo ThinkPad T440p, one of the few machines listed as Ubuntu-certified hardware

Comment: Press escape key to see progress. You will be able to isolate source of delay.

Comment: That depends on your specifications (machine) but on average it's not more than 10 minutes. That's the maximum I'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

When I loaded Ubuntu 14.04 from USB, it took me about an fifty minutes for the installer to finally tell me that it could not proceed. I tried twice from two different USBs with two different 14.04 downloads.

I figured that I wasn't able to get a non-corrupted version for whatever reason so instead I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 from http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Then after I fully installed that, Ubuntu prompted me to update to 14.04 which installed in less than 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It takes an average of 1-8 minutes to load from a Live-USB depending on your computer speed. if it is taking a long time, you may need to re-try making the Live-USB.